# Why doesn't 2-opt return an optimal solution?

Tags: heuristics, traveling-salesman

To find a solution for the Traveling Salesman Problem (TSP), one way to go is an algorithm called 2-opt, which is explained below.

```
The 2-opt algorithm basically removes two edges
from the tour, and reconnects the two paths created.
This is often refered to as a 2-opt move. There is only
one way to reconnect the two paths so that we still
have a valid tour (figure 1).  We do this only if the
new tour will be shorter. Continue removing and re-
connecting the tour until no 2-opt improvements can
be found. The tour is now 2-optimal.
```

For me, this algorithm tries all possibilities for edge combinations, so it should return the best (optimal) solution, right? Wrong, because :

```
If we look at the tour as a permutation of all the
cities, a 2-opt move will result in reversing a segment
of the permutation. 
Running the 2-opt heuristic will often result in a tour
with a length less than 5% above the Held-Karp bound.
```

My question is ; why does it not return the optimal solution? Does it not try all possible edge combinations? Can you give an example graph for which 2-opt doesn't give an optimal solution?
I'm citing from here : https://web.tuke.sk/fei-cit/butka/hop/htsp.pdf

Comment: You can give such an example. Just try a few graphs. This heuristic is known as *local search*. You start with some solution and then make local improvements, until you get stuck at a *local optimum*. A local optimum need not be a global optimum.

Comment: A concrete example can be found [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/7487/ea033b1729fb7695841673ece0e4782fdb88.pdf). See also [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.52.8674&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which mentions an $\Omega(\sqrt{n})$ lower bound and proves a matching $O(\sqrt{n})$ upper bound.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus which one is the example? figure 3? because in figure 3, the path chosen can be shorter by using 2-opt if I'm not mistaken...

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I posted an answer following your advice to try some graphs, can you correct me in it if needed?

Comment: The paper gives an example in which the second best tour differs from the best one in many edges. In particular, it is a local optimum for any local search only considering moves affecting fewer edges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I understand now after trying some examples as Yuval Filmus suggested. In the example below, we can get stuck on the local optimum using 2-opt, but as we can see the global optimum is better.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In reality, 2-opt might actually give you the optimal solution in fact odds are good that it very often does. But, to prove this requires brute force NP-complete travelling salesman solution. So it might give you the best solution for a particular dataset but you can't know this is optimal rather than pareto-optimal without an NP-complete operation.

Comment: Of course, brute force is not the only exact algorithm for TSP. I think it's also quite optimistic to say that 2-opt often gives you an optimal solution; depends heavily.